# How do I use QFIL to flash an image to a Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ board?

Tags: embedded, flash

I am software engineer with no embedded development experience and have been handed a board (Qualcomm® Snapdragon™) with

1: an image (Automotive Grade Linux: Halibut release)
2: flashing instructions

I need to flash a new image to the board

However, I am having great difficulty trying to figure out how to get this to work.

The instructions I have (which are not from Qualcomm) say that DIP switches 1&2 must be turned on in order to flash.

When I turn DIP switches 1&2 on, the board does not boot an OS, but QFIL does NOT detect it like it is supposed to:

[image: DIP switches 1&2 ON]

By contrast, when DIP switches 1&2 are OFF, the board DOES boot the OS, but QFIL detects the device as it is NOT supposed to do.:

[image]

Do I have bad hardware or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe it is because it's running in a vm and qfil can't dael with some aspect of it? Also: did you put the device in download mode (if it has one)? I'm not familiar with Qualcomm or arm development, so unfortunately I have no idea how to convert to .sdimg...

Comment: But did you read the board's / chip's datasheet? There should be at least something.

Comment: @rudib: Indeed it is running in a vm with usb3 enabled. Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the documentation I have been given doesn’t answer these questions and I am unable to determine where to acquire more or how to get help from Qualcomm.

Comment: do you know which board it is?

Comment: @rudib: Fair question. Unfortunately, I’m not allowed to say. It’s a new one that hardly anyone is using yet. SnapDragon SoC.

Comment: Hmmm. From what I found, the device must be in EDL/9006 mode for it to work. There seems to be at least one tool out there that supports firehose: https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/guides/qdl.md.html

Comment: Also, as this is proprietary hardware (with almost no public documentation), the only way the get definitive answers is the manufacturer. Try signign up for a qualcomm id at qualcomm.com. And if it doesn't work out, write them an email.

Comment: But you could also try asking on the EEVBlog forum (embedded computing), there may be someone familiar with the process...

Comment: @rudib: Excellent information and suggestions. Thank you so much.